# How to play a NSData in video player

Tags: iphone

I have written an async call to download a video of mp4 format. The response result is an NSData. How can I open the NSData in any video player framework which should be supported in IOS 3.

Comment: You don't say what format the video is in, or what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSData is basically a container object, and thus not in a format you can play in a video player. Without seeing any code, or the results of your data, you can create an NSString from data with

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now that you have a string, you can create an NSURL with

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
```

From there, you should be able to pass this into an MPMoviePlayerController with

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
```

Comment: Marked up as helped but there are a couple of syntax errors (UTF8 should be NSUTF8 and there is an extra ] in the last line.

Comment: I wrote this off the cuff and not in Xcode, so thanks for catching the mistakes. I've updated the answer to fix those.

Comment: @jmstone - It didn't work out at all for me. Where am I going wrong? `- (IBAction)playVideoBtn:(id)sender {
   NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self.media valueForKey:@"movie"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
`

Comment: Are you getting data out of your dictionary? Is that data being turned into a valid string?

Comment: Just checked, the movieURL is null. I have other data on the screen I'm going from for the same bit of core data. date, title and so on. Also a thumbnail frame of the video. So no reason that there should be a movie. The dataString is null too.

Comment: @jmstone - Anyway I can load the Binary Data to MPMoviePlayerController from the DB? I can see the date, so the record is active.

Comment: What is self.media? An NSManagedObject? An NSDictionary? If dataString is nil, then that is the source of your problem.

Comment: The response result is data... not anything like a url! One option is to write your data to a temporary file, then create a url from that file to send to a movie player.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to directly play the NSData into AVPlayer. What you can do is download the Data into Document folder and later fetch the file path and give that path to AVPlayer.