# In Objective C, how to play a video file in NSData without saving as a local file?

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I am working on an app to show confidential data in UIWebview. All data cannot be stored on the device.

I am able to show contents and graphics by the NSData directly and I am now working on the video player. However I find it always require a local file path or a URL to play.

For example:

```
[Webview loadHTMLString:strVedio baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

May I ask whether there are anyway to play the video file from NSData directly? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use remote url to play video? you somehow get the video -  you firstly downloaded it from the remote to NSData, so just pass that url to loadHTMLString: baseURL:

Comment: It's because the video data is embedded and encrypted with numbers of items. I am not able to have a simple URL to tough this video file. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042225/how-to-play-a-nsdata-in-video-player ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to build an internal server working like a proxy, so that every request for the data will pass through your proxy server in localhost, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952163/7361753. With this, you will have an url for AVPlayer to play the video from NSData directly as the proxy streams data to it. I have tried this in my project of Swift 3 with this module https://github.com/httpswift/swifter , and it works pretty well , but if you want to work asynchronously such that the data have not been prepared yet on request, you may need to hack the module a little bit, so that the socket will not closed after giving out the first response.